# pdfbox given coordinates vs XML(same pdf converted to xml) coordinates are mismatching?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

By using PDFBOX I extracted text coordinates. And I converted PDFto xml using

```
pdf2txt.py -t xml input.pdf output.xml
```

When I compared the both the coordinates there is some mismatch is there. May I know the reason why, And is there any way to get extract coordinates.

```
pdfbox
        [157.1999969482422, 727.4400024414062, 170.68670654296875, 727.4400024414062] -C
        [170.68670654296875, 727.4400024414062, 183.14602661132812, 727.4400024414062] -p
        [183.14602661132812, 727.4400024414062, 193.5319061279297, 727.4400024414062] -4
        [193.5319061279297, 727.4400024414062, 198.724853515625, 727.4400024414062] -' '
        
        xml
        [157.200,723.621,170.687,741.141] -C
        [170.687,723.621,183.146,741.141] -p
        [183.146,723.621,193.532,741.141] -4
        [193.532,723.621,198.725,741.141] -' '
```

This is the  [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KO56avrAP9ukH6f7DRObP57as3HW2x86/view?usp=sharing) I used.

Comment: Most likely deviations due to `float` usage. If you want more accuracy, you'll have to patch the classes of the PDFBox parser framework and the base `COSFloat` and `COSNumber` types to use `double` or even `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @mkl If you verify y1 in both coordinates its almost 3 pixel difference is there. May I consider this as decimal rounding lose?

Comment: 723 is from the bounding box. 727 is the baseline. You can see this with the development version of PDFDebugger https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ and activate the colored rectangles in the view menu.

Comment: Indeed, just like @Tilman writes. FascinatingCoder, you would have made it easier for a reader of your question if you had already there directed the focus to that larger difference. As your question looks now, only the rounding effects leap to the eye.

Answer (score 0):

The image below is from a rendering with [PDFDebugger 3.0](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/) (from the development trunk), but it can also be created with the DrawPrintTextLocations.java from the examples subdirectory in the 2.0.* release source code download.

[image]

The lower red line is at y=727 and is the base line of the font, the lower blue line is at y=723 and is from the bounding box of that font. So the two tools are giving different values. The PDFBox tool you used is likely the PrintTextLocations.java example.

(The upper lines don't match, because the upper red line is an heuristic value, and the upper blue line doesn't match because the font is rendered invisibly for OCR)